# Using OpenSSL in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, soap, openssl, pthreads

I have been writing a SOAP client application in C++ on Ubuntu using OpenSSL for my HTTPS transport and pthreads for threading. I have a number of threads - one central data acquisition thread which periodically gets worker threads to make SOAP requests via shared mutex protected queues.

Reading the documentation for OpenSSL I found [Is OpenSSL thread-safe?](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1) in the OpenSSL FAQ which describes the mechanisms required to ensure thread safety when using OpenSSL. I implemented this and all works fine.

The reason for my question is a conceptual difficulty really. I was thinking about implementing the same functionality that my application has already, but instead of using threads, I would create 2 seperate **applications** : One for the worker thread (of which multiple copies would be running) and another for the main data acquisition thread. I would then use TCP sockets to communicate between the two rather than mutex protected queues. This may be a bad idea but that is not really important - what is confusing me is **would I have to implement the same functions required to ensure OpenSSL thread safety in this second approach or not?**

My guess is that I would not have to and they could be treated as independent (indeed surely it must be as so many applications use OpenSSL) but what is the reason for it?? **What is different between multiple *applications* using shared library code and multiple *threads* sharing the same code??**  I have been writing multithreaded applications successfully for a couple of years now and it concerns me that I cannot come up with an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when multiple *threads* share the same library code, they also share the same global data structures; when multiple processes share that library code, they don't.

For example, many of the cryptographic algorithms in OpenSSL are faster if they have a large precalculated table available.  This table is shared between multiple threads calling the same OpenSSL functions, but locking must be used to ensure that only one thread attempts to initialise the table on first use.

As another example, many OpenSSL functions internally access the random number generator, but the state of this is a global data structure that must have its accessed synchronised across threads.

Comment: Thanks very much - this is precisely the kind of explanation I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

I would think the main difference is that in **multiple threads sharing the same code**, synchronization can be done if required, whereas in **multiple applications using shared library code** this is not easily possible other than with mechanisms such as file locking. Also, there would be considerable performance gain.

Consider an e.g. application which contains a **display(msg)** method which just writes to the screen, and a main() which invokes display(msg). If there are **five threads** calling this method, we would be able to synchronize the calls so that the output does not get garbled. However if the display(msg) method was implemented in **five different applications** and TCP sockets were used for sending the msg from the main application, the output will get garbled.

So in your situation, it depends on what the worker threads are trying to do with OpenSSL. From my understanding, they are making separate SSL connections, and so thread safety would not be required within an application. But there will be a performance overhead as a simple function call converts to TCP communication between two applications, and I think the overhead incurred would be much more than the benefit of having single-thread applications.

Comment: I will in reality stick with my multithreaded application. I just have difficulty seeing the distinction between 5 threads with a separate connection each need custom written lock code for OpenSSL but 5 separate processes each with separate connection dont require it.

Comment: I found the problem very interesting. In all situations I know of where multi-threading is used, locking is required only if the threads are contending for a resource. So this situation is an exception. As they are separate connections, OpenSSL should be able to handle them and therein lies the issue. If you are actually comparing the performance of both cases, please do update.