# SSL read and SSL write simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, ssl

I have two threads, `mainThread` and `recvThread`.

On `recvThread`, I call `SSL_read(ssl, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer))`. This blocks the thread until data is received.

Then, on `mainThread` I get told that some data needs to be sent. So, I call `SSL_write(ssl, someData, sizeof(someData))`.

Sometimes, this works fine. Other times, this fails with wierd internal error messages. My guess is that I can't call SSL_write whilst an SSL_read is occurring on the same `ssl` context. This makes total sense to me, but how do I fix it?

Do I make `recvThread` do something like:

```
SSL * ssl;
std::string data;
boost::mutex dataMutex;

while (recvThreadShouldBeRunning) {
    char readBuffer[100];
    auto nRead = SSL_read(ssl, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer)); //Non-blocking call to SSL_read.

    // Do something with nRead (handle errors, use data)

    {
        auto dataLock = boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>(dataMutex);
        if (data.length() > 0)
        {
            SSL_write(ssl, data.c_str(), data.length());
        }
    }
    sleep(50);
}
```

and then when I need to send something...

```
{
    auto dataLock = boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>(dataMutex);
    data = "some data";
}
```

This seems like it will work, but I think it is a rather ugly solution to my problem. Is there a way to somehow `SSL_lock()` `SSL_wait_on_data()` `SSL_unlock()`? Or is this the best way to go about it?

What is the standard way to go about this sort of problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you looked at ? [OpenSSL threads](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html)

Comment: Note that socket providers do not guarantee two different threads can read and write on the same socket at the same time.  But it seems to work.

Comment: @brianbeuning TCP guarantees that. It's a full-duplex connection.

Comment: @EJP I'm afraid that no matter what TCP guarantees, SSL does not guarantee it... As I said, I'm getting strange internal errors only some of the time, really good indication of thread problems. So normally with winsock, you'd just do what I'm doing now right? And that would be fine?

Comment: Related question: [Using OpenSSL (C++ on Ubuntu) in a multi-threaded (pthreads) manner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11251859).

Comment: Related question: [C++ call back function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17280301).

Comment: Related question: [OpenSSL and multi-threads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3417706).

Comment: @AStupidNoob I was specifically replying to a specific statement about 'socket providers'. SSL libraries are not socket providers.

Answer (score 1):

The quote from the documentation seems to contain the answer:

> OpenSSL can safely be used in multi-threaded applications provided that at least two callback functions are set, locking_function and threadid_func.
>
> `locking_function(int mode, int n, const char *file, int line)` is needed to perform locking on shared data structures. (Note that OpenSSL uses a number of global data structures that will be implicitly shared whenever multiple threads use OpenSSL.) Multi-threaded applications will crash at random if it is not set.
>
> `locking_function()` must be able to handle up to `CRYPTO_num_locks()` different mutex locks. It sets the n-th lock if `mode` & `CRYPTO_LOCK`, and releases it otherwise.
>
> `file` and `line` are the file number of the function setting the lock. They can be useful for debugging.
>
> -- [threads - OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html).

[The example of using the locking-related functions (github)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/threads/mttest.c):

> crypto/threads/mttest.c shows examples of the callback functions on Solaris, Irix and Win32.
>
> -- [threads - OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html).

Comment: This does not mean you can read/write to the same SSL handle at the same time.